# javascript set.has() is not a function

Tags: typescript, function, set, prototype

I have defined an `answerOption` type like this:

```
answerOptions:
          | {
              answerId: ObjectID;
              answerString: string;
              voters: Set<ObjectID>;
            }[]
          | undefined;
```

if I do this now

```
answerOptions?.reduce(
        (result, answerOption) => {
          result[answerOption.answerId.toHexString()] = {
            answerString: answerOption.answerString,
            answerVotes: answerOption.voters.size,
            didUserVote: answerOption.voters.has(
              new ObjectID(context.decoded.userId)
            ),
          };
          return result;
        },
        {}
      );
```

it tells me, that `voters.has()` is not a function. But it does not error on `voters.size`, both are prototype functions of the `Set` object in javascript.

[image: voter is of type Set]

added runtime log:

```
ANSWEROPTION {
  "answerId": "6009a6d491a6f040229b9381",
  "answerString": "oooooo",
  "voters": {}
}
```

gets inserted into mongoDB with this:

```
answerId: new ObjectID(),
answerString: option.answerString,
voters: new Set(),
```

Comment: May you tell us what `answerOption.voters` is inside the reduce?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You don't *execute* `.size`. It seems that the object you have isn't a set, so `.size` probably just returns `undefined`. I suspect you've used a type assertion somewhere and tricked the compiler into thinking you have a set when you don't. Also, this is TypeScript.

Comment: also sets work on values, not full object references so `.has` will fail.

Comment: @evolutionxbox added a screenshot in the original post. It's of type `Set<ObjectID>`

Comment: @Baesm that's not a runtime log. Please may you share its value using `console.log`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox posted a runtime log. did `console.log("ANSWEROPTION " + JSON.stringify(answerOption, null, 2));`

Comment: There's no need to stringify the output. --- `voters` looks like an empty object. What defines `answerOptions`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox gets inserted into mongoDB with the structure I added in original comment. So what happens is, that typescript can't differ between a simpel object and a set right? If I try parsing it to a set it says 'object is not iterable`

Comment: I don't think you can extract data from mongodb as a set.

Comment: Can mongoDB store Sets even? Or do they get serialized.

Comment: @evolutionxbox so If I retrieve it from mongodb, do I need to parse it into a set?

Comment: @MinusFour even if they would get serialized, I would be able to retrieve them from mongodb and parse them into sets again right?

Comment: @Baesm You should, as long as mongodb isn't serializing them wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ I think that's exactly what happens. So I need to parse it into a Set again right?

Comment: @Baesm I suppose so, however I'm not familiar enough with Mongo. I'm not sure what the best way to define serialisation/deserialisation for it.

Comment: @MinusFour seems like it. Tried quick and dirty to do `answerVotes: new Set(answerOption.voters).size`  throws `object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`. So seems like this is not a working Set at all.

Comment: @Baesm if not iterable then maybe you are sending a normal object instead of an array (which is a more suitable representation). So you might need to convert the set into an array when you store the Set and viceversa when you retrieve the Set.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean hasOwnProperty() ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has